# Integration of a real powered rational expression

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, matlab, real-numbers, fundamental-solution

Peace be upon you,

I've encountered this pretty integral
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1&\frac{x^{\alpha+\beta-1}-x^{\alpha-1}}{x-1}dx,\\ \\
&\alpha,\beta\in\Re^+
\end{align*}
It seems much simpler than a question; but as I implied some of the known integration techniques like: Substitution, Polynomial division, Term by term integration, it was not solved.

Even I used Matlab Mupad and set the necessary assumptions and then performed the integration, but no results occurred.

Can anyone light up any idea?

Comment: Do you know the digamma function?

Comment: Think about Beta function

Comment: Yes I know; I encountered to Digamma function while analyzing my problem to create a system of equations and the above equation is one part of one of the equations of the system. but since this integral is definite, I don't suppose that I can use Digamma function to solve it.
As a matter of fact, if I needed an approximate solution, I could exploit the sigma form of the Digamma function and reach an answer; but I am seeking for an analytic solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may write

$$\frac{x^{\alpha+\beta-1}-x^{\alpha-1}}{1-x} = (x^{\alpha+\beta-1}-x^{\alpha-1})\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k,$$

then

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{x^{\alpha+\beta-1}-x^{\alpha-1}}{1-x}\mathrm{d}x
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_0^1 (x^{\alpha+\beta-1}-x^{\alpha-1})x^k\mathrm{d}x\\\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k+\alpha+\beta} - \frac{1}{k+\alpha}\right)\\\\
&= - \psi(\alpha+\beta)+\psi(\alpha)
\end{align}$$

by the well-known series representation of the $\psi$ function [DLMF: here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7#%C2%A75.7(ii)%20Other%20Series) 5.7.6.

Comment: Yes you are right but the story is a little different. I am seeking for solution of the system
\begin{align*}
&\psi(\alpha)-\psi(\alpha+\beta)=c_1\\
&\psi(\beta)-\psi(\alpha+\beta)=c_2
\end{align*}
I tried to convert it to integral, hope to find an analytic solution for values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: So, if the result is supposed to be a function, I need it to be one revertible function.

Comment: @hossayni OK, this is more challenging :)!

Answer (score 0):

Using the same approach as Olivier Oloa in his answer :

- for the antiderivative $$\int \frac{x^{\alpha+\beta-1}-x^{\alpha-1}}{x-1}\,dx=x^{\alpha } \left(\frac{1}{\alpha }-\frac{x^{\beta }}{\alpha +\beta
     }\right)-B_x(\alpha +\beta +1,0)+B_x(\alpha +1,0)$$
- for the integral $$\int_0^1 \frac{x^{\alpha+\beta-1}-x^{\alpha-1}}{x-1}\,dx=\psi ^{(0)}(\alpha +\beta )-\psi ^{(0)}(\alpha )$$

Comment: @OlivierOloa.Thanks for pointing : what was wrong was the lhs I typed too fast ! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The n-th [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) is $~H_n=\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x~~}dx.~$ Some particular values can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Special_values_for_fractional_arguments).